# Java - swing listen an action in a text field of a form

Tags: java, forms, swing

I would like to develop a form with some text field.
example:

> ```
> Name
> SecondName
> ```

the idea is that every text field have inside a text like:

> ```
> Insert your name
> Insert your second name
> ```

when you click on the first text field to write your name, the text "Insert your name" have to be deleted... the same have to happen for the second text field (SecondName).
The effect have to be this:
[image]

I think that i just need an Action on the text field that have to wake up when the user press on the mouse on the text field, it's possible?
Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Take a look at `PromptSupport` in [SwingLabs SwingX Library](https://maven.java.net/#nexus-search;gav~org.swinglabs.swingx~swingx-all~~~~kw,versionexpand)

**For Example**

[image: Prompt fields]

When the fields have focus, the "prompt" will be hidden, but you can control this, making it shown until the user types something or highlight when focus is gained.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.prompt.BuddySupport;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.prompt.PromptSupport;

public class PromptSupportTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PromptSupportTest();
    }

    public PromptSupportTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            JTextField firstName = new JTextField(10);
            PromptSupport.setPrompt("First Name", firstName);
            PromptSupport.setFocusBehavior(PromptSupport.FocusBehavior.HIDE_PROMPT, firstName);

            JTextField lastName = new JTextField(10);
            PromptSupport.setPrompt("Last Name", lastName);
            PromptSupport.setFocusBehavior(PromptSupport.FocusBehavior.HIDE_PROMPT, lastName);

            JTextField picture = new JTextField(10);
            PromptSupport.setPrompt("Picture", picture);
            PromptSupport.setFocusBehavior(PromptSupport.FocusBehavior.HIDE_PROMPT, picture);

            JButton browse = new JButton("...");
            browse.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
            browse.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            browse.setFocusPainted(false);
            browse.setFocusable(false);
            browse.setOpaque(false);
            // Add action listener to brose button to show JFileChooser...

            BuddySupport.addRight(browse, picture);

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            gbc.weightx = 1;

            add(firstName, gbc);
            add(lastName, gbc);
            add(picture, gbc);

            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
            add(new JButton("Ok"), gbc);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

I've also added an example of `BuddySupport` which is part of the same API, which allows you to "buddy" another component with a text component.  Here I've done the classic "file browser" combination, but I do "search" style fields like this all the time...

Comment: +1 i was just to comment to put an example :D good answer :). Actually he could be interested also in `BuddySupport`

Comment: @nachokk Oh god! I love `BuddySupport`!

Comment: thank you, but i dont know how can i download and setup the library PromptSupport. i mean: which jar file i have to download? and where i have to put this file? thank you

Comment: Start with [swingx-all-1.6.3.jar](https://java.net/downloads/swingx/releases/swingx-all-1.6.3.jar)...I'd probably also grab a copy of the JavaDocs.  Where to put will come down to the IDE you are using.  In Netbeans, I keep a nice "common libraries" folder where I store libraries I re-use often and then simply add it to the projects "library"

Comment: @MadProgrammer thank you it works perfectly, please say hi to Melbourne for me ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: If this is indeed the new link for [SwingX[(https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.swinglabs.swingx/swingx-project/1.6.5-1), kindly do replace it.

Comment: I updated the SwingX link. Also, the call to `PromptSupport.setFocusBehavior(PromptSupport.FocusBehavior.HIDE_PROMPT, ...)` is not needed in this case since that is the default behaviour.

Comment: @IvanRF Yes, but's also a nice demonstration of the API for those who might not have used it before ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer of course, I'm one of those :) didn't know about `PromptSupport`. Thanks for the example code!

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [Text Prompt](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/text-prompt/) for a simple solution that allows you to control when the text is displayed/hidden as well as the font/color of the text.

It will work with regular text components. In its simplest form you only need one extra line of code:

```
JTextField firstName = new JTextField(10);
TextPrompt tp = new TextPrompt("First Name", firstName);
```

Answer (score 1):

see this example

```
import java.awt.Color;  
 import java.awt.Font;  
 import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;  
 import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;  
 import javax.swing.JTextField;  

 public class HintTextField extends JTextField {  

   Font gainFont = new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11);  
   Font lostFont = new Font("Tahoma", Font.ITALIC, 11);  

   public HintTextField(final String hint) {  

     setText(hint);  
     setFont(lostFont);  
     setForeground(Color.GRAY);  

     this.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {  

       @Override  
       public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {  
         if (getText().equals(hint)) {  
           setText("");  
           setFont(gainFont);  
         } else {  
           setText(getText());  
           setFont(gainFont);  
         }  
       }  

       @Override  
       public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {  
         if (getText().equals(hint)|| getText().length()==0) {  
           setText(hint);  
           setFont(lostFont);  
           setForeground(Color.GRAY);  
         } else {  
           setText(getText());  
           setFont(gainFont);  
           setForeground(Color.BLACK);  
         }  
       }  
     });  

   }  
 }
```

Comment: What happens if you call `setText` programmatically?