# Making a JTextField background transparent

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I'm trying to make the background for a JTextField transparent, that way so the JLabel underneath it is still visible, but whenever entering text into the JTextField you can see the text. Here's what I have now basically.

The JTextField background is set to black in the below picture.
[image]

In theory, if the JTextField's background was transparent it should look like this.
[image]

So, my question is how would I make the JTextField's background transparent?

Comment: Did you use .setOpaque(false); ?

Comment: Yeah, I made sure to set it to false

Comment: Try .setColor(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));

Comment: That isn't a valid color identifier.

Comment: @Noob That's a very dangerous suggesting as the paint engine doesn't know that it needs to notify the components below to update themselves when the top level component changes, causing repaint issues and artifacts.

Comment: You wish to consider using `PromptSupport` from the SwingLabs API, have a look at [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578568/java-swing-listen-an-action-in-a-text-field-of-a-form/20578601#20578601) for more details

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This example does simple use `setOpaque(false)`. The labels text is always visible. I tested it with Java 1.7 and 1.8. So if it does not work for you, what else did you do, to initalize your frame?

```
public class TextField extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public TextField() {
        initComponents();
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        jLabel1.setText("Test");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel1);
        jLabel1.setBounds(60, 40, 70, 14);

        jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");
        jTextField1.setOpaque(false);
        getContentPane().add(jTextField1);
        jTextField1.setBounds(50, 30, 90, 40);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new TextField().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: I figured it out, when initializing the frame it did this..
javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());

Comment: Why without setBounds? I did not use any layout manager. Why not placing my Components like this?

Comment: it works for JTextArea too just one line `textArea.setOpaque(false);`

Answer (score 1):

Change look and feel setting to metal or window
It will work if u have set it transparent already
Nimbus laf makes textareas backgroung visible as soon as the program runs

Comment: Mac OS X laf supports transparent background too.  Nimbus seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Nimbus does not support transparent background in JTextField, JTextArea etc.  Instead of making the background transparent, here is code to make the component set its background color to match its parent's background:

```
private static final HierarchyListener _hl = new HierarchyListener() {

    @Override
    public void hierarchyChanged(HierarchyEvent e) {
        Component c = e.getComponent();
        for (Component p = c; p != null; p = p.getParent()) {
            if (p.isOpaque()) {
                int bk = p.getBackground().getRGB();
                c.setBackground(new Color(bk));
                break;
            }
        }

    }
};

public static void makeComponentCopyParentBackground(Component c) {
    c.removeHierarchyListener(_hl); // Guard against client calling multiple times.
    c.addHierarchyListener(_hl);
}
```