# Cannot get the JTextField to set text to null on keyPressed?

Tags: java

When I press a key in a userID box I want the text in the textbook to be erased when the first key is pressed.

I thought that the code below would do that but it is not erasing the text in the text field.

**How to set the text to empty in my JTextField?**

Code:

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    final Component source = e.getComponent();
    final JFrame frame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getRoot(source);

      if (source instanceof JTextField){
          ((JTextField) source).setText("");
          source.repaint();
      }
}
```

I should mention that my KeyListener is in a completely different class.

```
class myKeyListener implements KeyListener {

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        final Component source = e.getComponent();
        final JFrame frame = (JFrame) SwingUtilities.getRoot(source);

        JTextField tf = (JTextField)e.getSource();
        tf.setText("");  
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you actually using this code?  Can we see more of the program?

Comment: So when the user first types something into the userID field, you want the userID text to be removed? Next question is, why?

Comment: Once you get this working, you will have to add some logic to determine when you want to actually clear the `JTextField`.  Otherwise, it will clear it every time a key is pressed, which will mean that the user will never be able to type anything at all.

Comment: You may consider using a FocusListener, so that when focusGained is triggered, you could select all the text, this would allow the user to simply start typing to replace the content. If your trying to provide prompt support for your fields, you could consider using [PromptSupport from SwingLabs, SwingX libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578568/java-swing-listen-an-action-in-a-text-field-of-a-form/20578601#20578601)

Comment: How are you adding the KeyListener?

Answer (score 1):

Try using e.getSource():

```
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    JTextField tf = (JTextField)e.getSource();
    tf.setText("");
}
```

The above code leaves the typed character in the box. If you want to end up with no characters (although, I'm not sure why you would want to do this), then maybe you should put this code in keyReleased()?

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same as what the OP is doing?

Comment: I thought it wasn't working for OP. This is how I usually do it. But I think I see the issue now.

Comment: Oh, I see, you are calling `getSource()` rather than `getComponent()`.  You may want to point that out explicitly in your answer.

Comment: Is there a way to get a stacking order. I have to password fields on the same form that I want to compare every time a key is pressed.

Comment: When the keyPressed() event happens, get the text from both text fields and compare them.

Answer (score 1):

It's much easier to select the text in the JTextField, so when the user types a character, the text disappears.

```
    JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
    textField.setText("Type in something here");
    textField.setSelectionStart(0);
    textField.setSelectionEnd(textField.getText().length());
```

Comment: This is in a keyListener class and not in the original class? I tried this and it still isn't working. What am i missing?

Comment: @Doug Hauf: This goes in the original class.  There's no need for a keyListener class.

Comment: What if that is what the boss wants to keep the good more refined as he puts it?