# Java Focused JTextField

Tags: java, swing, focus, actionlistener, jtextfield

I currently have a `JTextField` and inside that, I have default text.
The problem I currently have is getting that `JTextField` to have a working `ActionListener`. I have added an action listener to the component, but when I use `FocusListener` to check for focus, it will not give any output/reply.

Any help will be much appreciated. And please supply me with some example code of what I should change, thanks.

*PS. I am using this class as a component from another class, so in another class I wrote:*

```
window.add(smartTextField);
```

### SmartText.java

```
package com.finn.multiweb;

import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class SmartText extends JTextField {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    JTextField textField = new JTextField();

    String defaultText;

    boolean hasDefaultText;

    public SmartText() {
        super();
        hasDefaultText = false;
        notFocused();
    }

    public SmartText(String defaultText) {
        super(defaultText);
        this.defaultText = defaultText;
        hasDefaultText = true;
        notFocused();
    }

    private void notFocused() {
        super.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
        if (hasDefaultText == true) {
            super.setText(defaultText);
        } else if (hasDefaultText == false) {
            super.setText("");
        }
    }

    private void isFocused() {
        super.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        super.setText("");
    }

    private void focusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
            System.out.println("test");
        }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 0):

You've not added a `FocusListener` to the field

```
// You need to implement the FocusListener interface
public class SmartText extends JTextField implements FocusListener {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    JTextField textField = new JTextField();

    String defaultText;

    boolean hasDefaultText;

    public SmartText() {
        super();
        hasDefaultText = false;
        notFocused();
        // Then register yourself as interested in focus events
        addFocusListener(this);
    }

    public SmartText(String defaultText) {
        super(defaultText);
        this.defaultText = defaultText;
        hasDefaultText = true;
        notFocused();
        // Then register yourself as interested in focus events
        addFocusListener(this);
    }

    // Then implement the contract of the FocusListener interface
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
    }

    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
    }
```

Take a read through [How to Write a Focus Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html) for more details

From the looks of your code, you trying to add "prompt support" to the field, you may consider using the `PromptSupport` from the SwingLabs, SwingX libraries, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578568/java-swing-listen-an-action-in-a-text-field-of-a-form/20578601#20578601)

Comment: How can I do so? (Please provide me with code)  EDIT: But I DO have a focusGained() {} field so shouldn't that work???

Comment: Ahh! Thankyou SO much! In 7 minutes when it lets me I will vote, cheers and thanks again.

Comment: @user3640377 Perhaps you should take some time to read through the tutorials first [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/), they'll probably answer a lot more of your future questions ;)

Comment: Yeah with the PromptSupport, I am actually trying to create a library with a ton of classes, so its sort of like recreating something from SwingX (never actually heard of it until now though) So thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Text Prompt](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/text-prompt/) which is a single class.

Answer (score 0):

To work with FocusListener Interface and in order to listen’s the keyboards gaining or losing focus, the listener object created from class is need to registered with a component using the component’s addFocusListener() method. The two important method focusGained(FocusEvent e) and void focusLost(FocusEvent e) which helps to find which component is focused.

Take a read through [What is FocusListener Interface and How it Work](http://programmingguide.org/what-is-focuslistener-interface-and-how-it-works/) and [Validate Text Field Using FocusListener Interface in Java](http://programmingguide.org/validate-text-field-using-focuslistener-interface-in-java/) for more details with proper examples.