# Prompt for JTextField makes it shade gray

Tags: java, swing, prompt, swingx, digit

I am playing around with Prompt's with JTextFields,

Just one problem:

[image: Prompt]

As you can see, The background is shaded gray a little, I even tried to set the background color to white and it is still gray. Heres my current code for setting a prompt:

```
final JTextField aText = new JTextField(6);
final JTextField bText = new JTextField(6);  
PromptSupport.setPrompt("Digit", aText);
```

Is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: What is `PromptSupport`?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels `PromptSupport` is an API available in SwingX

Comment: What OS?  What JDK?  What Look and Feel? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels If you're really interested, you could have a [look at this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578568/java-swing-listen-an-action-in-a-text-field-of-a-form/20578601#20578601) which demonstrates it...

Comment: This appears to be a bug with Mac OS X and `PromptSupport`...or at least that's where it appears for me...

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug between `PromptSupport` and MaxOS X (or at least that's where I had problems)

I tried using `PromprtSupport.setBackground` but that didn't seem to work, so I ended up using `PromptSupport.setBackgroundPainter` instead

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.painter.Painter;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.prompt.PromptSupport;

public class TestPrompt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestPrompt();
    }

    public TestPrompt() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JTextField prompt = new JTextField(20);
                PromptSupport.setPrompt("Go ahead, make my day", prompt);
                PromptSupport.setFocusBehavior(PromptSupport.FocusBehavior.SHOW_PROMPT, prompt);
                PromptSupport.setBackgroundPainter(new Painter() {
                    @Override
                    public void paint(Graphics2D g, Object object, int width, int height) {
                        g.setColor(UIManager.getColor("TextField.background"));
                        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
                    }
                }, prompt);

                prompt.setOpaque(true);
                JTextField noPrompt = new JTextField(20);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
                gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
                gbc.insets = new Insets(4, 4, 4, 4);
                frame.add(prompt, gbc);
                frame.add(noPrompt, gbc);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

This is a work around, not a solution as there are still some issues...

Comment: Works for me on Mac OS 10.9 and Java 8. What are you using?

Comment: 10.9.4, Hmm... I didn't copy paste it.

Comment: Admittdly, I was running the OSX in a virtual box, but it should work.  I'll test it when I get home

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Little bit of coordinates I had to change for rectangle as white color was spilling over. But rest all is fine.