# Creating custom JRadioButton with JtextField?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, custom-component, jradiobutton

I want to make `JTextField` part of `JRadioButton` or hook them together.
my intention is to let the user fill in the text field when he selects the radio button. For this reason I have created custom radio button which extends from `JradioButton`. I should be able to add it to `buttonGroup`

```
ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup()
RadioButtonWithTextField radio1 = RadioButtonWithTextField("only to");
RadioButtonWithTextField radio2 = RadioButtonWithTextField("not only to");
buttonGroup.add(radio1 );
buttonGroup.add(radio1 );
radio1.setSelected(true);
```

[image]

The problem is, my TextField does not adjust it's size according to what I type in it or setText to it programmatically.

If I change the text of radio button after displaying the component it does not show all part of it.

Does anyone know or have experience in custom component creation?

```
public class RadioButtonWithTextField extends JRadioButton {
    private JTextField textField;

    public RadioButtonWithTextField(String text) {
        super(text);
        createComponents();
        layoutComponents();
    }

    private void createComponents() {
       textField = new WebTextField("",30);
       textField.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(60,20));
    }

    private void layoutComponents() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING,2,2));
        add(textField);
    }

    public WebTextField getTextField() {
        return textField;
    }

    public void setTextField(WebTextField textField) {
        this.textField = textField;
    }

}
```

Comment: Start by creating a class which extends from `JPanel`, apply the appropriate layout manager for your needs, add the `JRadioButton` and `JTextField` to it.  Provide setters and getters for the most common operations (`set/getText`, `set/isSelected`, `add/removeActionListener`)

Comment: Depending on your needs, you might also be able to use the `BuddySupport` API from SwingLab's SwingX library, demonstrated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20578568/java-swing-listen-an-action-in-a-text-field-of-a-form/20578601#20578601)

Comment: Since you can only choose one radio button among a group, why not just have a group of radio button and one TextField, you don't need to couple  the TextField with any radio button.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I applied your way but i can not add it to ButtonGroup  `ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup()`

Comment: What is it that you can't add to buttonGroup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would follow @MadProgrammer's suggestion to create a JPanel class that consists of a JRadioButton and a JTextField. The below works for me.

```
public class RadioButtonPanel extends JPanel {
JRadioButton jRadioButton;
JTextField jTextField;

RadioButtonPanel(String radioButtonName) {
    jRadioButton = new JRadioButton(radioButtonName);
    jTextField = new JTextField(10);
    this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    this.add(jRadioButton);
    this.add(jTextField);

    jRadioButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            handleEvent();
        }
    });
}

private void handleEvent() {
    System.out.println(jRadioButton.getText() + " is selected, the customized text is " + jTextField.getText());
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();

    RadioButtonPanel radioButtonPanel1 = new RadioButtonPanel("Apple");
    RadioButtonPanel radioButtonPanel2 = new RadioButtonPanel("Banana");
    RadioButtonPanel radioButtonPanel3 = new RadioButtonPanel("Pear");
    ButtonGroup buttonGroup = new ButtonGroup();
    buttonGroup.add(radioButtonPanel1.jRadioButton);
    buttonGroup.add(radioButtonPanel2.jRadioButton);
    buttonGroup.add(radioButtonPanel3.jRadioButton);

    jFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1, 5, 5));
    jFrame.add(radioButtonPanel1);
    jFrame.add(radioButtonPanel2);
    jFrame.add(radioButtonPanel3);
    jFrame.pack();
    jFrame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

A sample UI would be:

[image]