# How to set placeholder from JDateChooser_Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, date, calendar, jdatechooser

I am using **JDateChooser** so that users can click calendar to select a date.
Currently, textfield next to the calendar starts with an empty field. Only when user selects date in the calendar, the date automatically gets filled into the textfield.

However, I'd like for users to **manually type dates** without having to use the calendar. In order to remind users of the date format, I'd like to use **place holder** like **'yyyy-mm-dd'** in the textfield.

However, the text field is not an object of JTextField but it came with an object of JDateChooser. JDateChooser doesn't have methods to set placeholder like what normally JTextField can do by setting texts.

```
JDateChooser textField = new JMIGDateChooser();
```

How can I go about this?
I'd appreciate your input!

Comment: If i remember correctly, `JDateChooser`  has a method like `getEditor()` that returns the editor component: a `JTextField` or a `JComboBox`...

Comment: Thank you. You are right! I was able to get the editor.

JTextComponent test = ((JTextComponent) textField .getDateEditor());
test.setText("hahaha");

but the string doesn't display in the GUI. I will do more investigation.

Comment: Try `TextPrompt`, cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20578858/230513).