# How to Create a JTextfield text watermark (Not actual Text)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt

How can I get a watermark placed inside of the `JTextfield` when it is empty?

All I am trying to do is get the username and password fields to display "username" and "password" in their respective `JTextField` and `JPasswordField` without being actual text. I know that I need an event listener to see if they are empty. I don't know how to display these messages, it would be just like above on Stack Overflow where it says "Search..." in grayed out letters and disappears whenever there is keyboard input. It should reappear if the string is empty again.

Please and thank you in advance.

```
public class HelloPrompt extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new HelloPrompt();
    }
    
    public HelloPrompt(){
        super("Login Page");
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Login");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        JButton b = new JButton("Submit");
        JLabel user = new JLabel("username: ");
        JTextField userEnt = new JTextField("username", 20);
        JLabel pass = new JLabel("password: ");
        JTextField passEnt = new JPasswordField("password", 20);
    
        p.add(user);
        p.add(userEnt);
        p.add(pass);
        p.add(passEnt);

        add(p);
        setSize(299,299);
        setVisible(true);
        
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Try [*Text Prompt*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20578858/230513) with an `Icon`.

Comment: I am adding "Text Prompt," through the link, is text prompt something that I can import? If so what is the import statement? Otherwise, I must create a constructor for Text Prompt, correct?

Comment: @MarioPichardo, `is text prompt something that I can import?` - it is just a class that  needs to be found in a directory that is on your classpath. For example you can put it in the same directory as your HelloPrompt class.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure on what you are trying to do but you can use

`userEnt.setText("Enter username: ")`
`passEnt.setText("Enter password: ")`

change its foreground color to something lighter like `GRAY`
when the user clicks the textfield, clear the textfield's text and reset its foregroud to black.

implement a listener for Lost Focus. If the textfield loses focus and the textfield's text is equal to nothing, reset the foreground color to `GRAY` and 
call this again

`userEnt.setText("Enter username: ")`
`passEnt.setText("Enter password: ")`